# ShareKit Facebook deep-linking

Tags: xcode, facebook, sharekit

I am using ShareKit 2.0 in my application. I would like to be able to link the post on facebook to my application, so when a user taps a link posted on facebook from my application(on a mobile device), the application would start or, if it is not installed, get redirected to my application on appstore. Is this achievable using ShareKit as I could not find any of this in their documentation. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You only have to enter the app's URL (Canvas URL) in the DefaultsSHKConfigurator.h (or it's subclass)
The you have to make sure that the type of SHKItem is URL, containing you application's URL. Then you should append the deeplink parameter to the URL, containing the information you want to receive.
Also, you must not forget to make the modifications to the facebook app according to their documentation.